# Ways to read/edit multiple lines in python

Tags: python, edit, lines

What i'm trying to do is to take 4 lines from a file that look like this:

```
@blablabla
blablabla #this string needs to match the amount of characters in line 4
!blablabla
blablabla #there is a string here
```

This goes on for a few hundred times.

I read the entire thing line by line, make a change to the fourth line, then want to match the second line's character count to the amount in the fourth line.

I can't figure out how to "backtrack" and change the second line after making changes to the fourth.

```
with fileC as inputA:
    for line1 in inputA:
        line2 = next(inputA)
        line3 = next(inputA)
        line4 = next(inputA)
```

is what i'm currently using, because it lets me handle 4 lines at the same time, but there has to be a better way as causes all sorts of problems when writing away the file. What could I use as an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do:

```
with open(filec , 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # readlines creates a list of the lines
```

to access line 4 and do something with it you would access:

```
lines[3] # as lines is a list
```

and for line 2

```
lines[1] # etc.
```

You could then write your lines back into a file if you wish

**EDIT:**

Regarding your comment, perhaps something like this:

```
def change_lines(fileC):

    with open(fileC , 'r') as f:
        while True:
            lines = []
            for i in range(4):
                try:
                    lines.append(f.next()) # f.next() returns next line in file
                except StopIteration: # this will happen if you reach end of file before finding 4 more lines. 
                    #decide what you want to do here
                    return
            # otherwise this will happen
            lines[2] = lines[4] # or whatever you want to do here
            # maybe write them to a new file
            # remember you're still within the for loop here
```

**EDIT:**

Since your file divides into fours evenly, this works:

```
def change_lines(fileC):
    with open(fileC , 'r') as f:
        while True:
            lines = []
            for i in range(4):
                try:
                    lines.append(f.next())
                except StopIteration:
                    return
            code code # do something with lines here
                      # and write to new file etc.
```

Comment: Isn't it generally a bad idea to put all of your lines in a single list? What if the input file is very large? Is it possible to only load the first four lines, do the edits, then grab the next 4 lines? What would this code look like?

Comment: I edited my post. You can do that with something like what I added. It works for me using f.next() anyway, though you may need to tinker with it. Catching the StopIteration is only necessary if you have a file that doesn't evenly divide into 4. So for instance, on the last iteration of the for loop you only have 2 or 3 lines left in the file etc. So you'll need to figure out what to do in that situation.

Comment: If your lists won't be too big though, you are probably fine with f.readlines

Comment: Thanks! The file does divide nicely into fours, so that isn't an issue. I'm going to give this a try first.

Comment: please let me know if this worked for you. And if you found this post solved your issue, please consider accepting it as the answer.

Comment: I made some changes to the code which I think make a bit more sense. At the bottom where it says 'code code' I unindented that line.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

def read_in_chunks(file_path, n):
    with open(file_path) as fh:
        while True:
            lines = list(islice(fh, n))
            if lines: yield lines
            else:     break

for lines in read_in_chunks(sys.argv[1], 4):
    print lines
```

Also relevant is the `grouper()` [recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the `itertools` module. In that case, you would need to filter out the `None` values before yielding them to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file with `.readlines` and then index which ever line you want to change and write that back to the file:

```
rf = open('/path/to/file')
file_lines = rf.readlines()
rf.close()

line[1] = line[3] # trim/edit however you'd like

wf = open('/path/to/write', 'w')
wf.writelines(file_lines)
wf.close()
```